# What are these slots for in this stone slab?

Tags: architecture

Does anyone know the purpose of these slots in this stone slab?

[image]

If it helps, the stone slab *may* have been taken from a nearby castle.

Also, there's another stone slab (also embedded in the wall) that is a mirror image.

Comment: Some more information, starting with current location; some context, is this the side of building or a garden wall; and image of other part, if it looks to match this part. You aren't giving us much to go on...

Comment: Without knowing how the stone was originally mounted, I can't see that this question can be provably answerable.

Answer (score 1):

What you called stone looks to me like concrete which has been poured around a form supported by temporary vertical members. Notice how the supports don't have matching height. Why this technique would have been used on that wall is another matter.

Comment: Nope - it's solid stone.

Comment: Let us know when you find out what kind of stone it is.

Comment: I'm not sure - if it helps the nearby castle is Wallingford castle - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallingford_Castle